# Where does the file goes when the user clicks on upload button from the jsp?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, apache-poi, xssf, hssf

When a user clicks on the upload button after selecting a file from their computer, where does that file goes? Can i use that file's content if a temp file is made? How can i do that?
I need my user to upload a file and then validation is performed on that file's content?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your application how its handles file uploads. In a Spring application, it is common to use [apache commons FileUpload](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartResolver.html).

`org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver` (that extends from `CommonsFuleUploadSupport`) has a property `uploadTempDir`. That can be used to specifiy where the uploaded file is temporary stored.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />
    <property name="uploadTempDir" ref="uploadTempDirResource" />
</bean>

<bean id="uploadTempDirResource"
      class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
    <constructor-arg value="/temp" />
</bean>
```

- @See [Spring Reference 3.2.x, Chapter 17.10 Spring (multipart) fileupload](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart)
- @See [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartResolver.html)